# unable to pass argument to angularjs directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am learning angularjs. I am facing problem while passing the parameter to the directive. 
if the template has `myJson` variable name instead of `{{jsonVar}}`, it is correctly displaying the table. But, when I am trying to pass the json object name through an argument `{{jsonVar}}` to the directive, it is not loading the template itself. Can any one help me why it is not working. 

In the controller, sample.json is being loaded into `myJson` variable 

Please let me know what is the mistake I am doing. Code sample is shown below: Plunkr URL is also posted for reference. 

Thanks in advance

```
    var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.myJson = null;
  $http.get('sample.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.myJson = data;
    console.log($scope.myJson);
  });
}).directive("myTable", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      jsonVar: '@'
    },
    template: "<table>" +
      "<thead >" +
      " <tr><td ng-repeat='(key,val) in {{jsonVar}}'>{{key}}</td></tr>" +
      "</thead>" +
      "<tbody>" +
      "<tr ng-repeat='obj in {{jsonVar}}'>" +
      "<td ng-repeat='(key,val) in obj'>{{val}} </td>" +
      "</tr>" +
      "</tbody>" +
      "</table>"

  };
});
```

I am passing the parameter to the directive as below:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>

 <my-table jsonVar="myJson"></my-table>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/RMe45N3bgJV5lYdNyetX?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is the reference to the **jsonVar**. You should change the scope definition of your directive to.

```js
  scope: {
    jsonVar: '=' // 2 way binding by reference
  }
```

Also camel cased attributes get transformed in dash separated in html.

```html
<my-table json-var="myJson"></my-table>
```

I would strongly recommend reading the documentation for directive found [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) no matter how long it may be.

Comment: I also have modified the {{jsonVar}} in template to jsonVar and it is working fine now. thanks for your response.